How can I truncate the text in DropDownPicker (react-native-dropdown-picker)?
While using DropDownPicker (in a react native expo project for android), I want to truncate long text at the placeholder.
For example, if the placeholder is
Select city

and the user selects
City of Massachusetts

from the dropdown list, then the placeholder should be
City of Massachu...

instead of
City of

(the word Massachusetts is hidden in the second line).
I tried these two styles:
textStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    flexWrap: 'nowrap',
    numberOfLines: 1,
    ellipsizeMode: 'tail',
}

and
placeholderStyle {
    flex: 1,
    flexWrap: 'nowrap',
    numberOfLines: 1,
    ellipsizeMode: 'tail',
}

but with no luck.
So the question is, how can I achieve truncation WITHOUT using a custom component?
I use these versions:
"expo": "~51.0.17"
"react": "18.2.0"
"react-native": "0.74.3"
"react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.6"

You can see the expo snack here: https://snack.expo.dev/@gchariton/dropdownpicker

Could you create an Expo snack? https://snack.expo.dev/

Here's the snack: https://snack.expo.dev/@gchariton/dropdownpicker

You should add this to the props
labelProps={{
  numberOfLines: 1
}}


Relative information How to have Ellipsis effect on Text

That solved the problem! Thank you!
